# Convexity of a certain function connected to the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose that we are given two vectors $x,y$ in a normed space $X$. Can we prove in general that the function $$t\mapsto \|x-ty\|$$ is convex?

It is certainly the case if the normed space has dimension 1.

EDIT: It is convex. One uses convexity of $|\langle x^*, x-ty\rangle|$ and passes to the supremum with $\|x^*\|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\pi(x_i) = y_i$?

Comment: Look at how the quotient norm is defined. That gives an immediate lower bound for $\lVert x_1 - x_2\rVert$ for all choices $x_i\in \pi^{-1}(y_i)$.

Comment: No, and there may not even be an $x_i \in \pi^{-1}(y_i)$ with norm $1$. But what do you know about $\{ \lVert x\rVert : \pi(x) = y_i\}$?

Comment: If $\pi(x) = y$, what do you know about $\lVert x\rVert$ and $\lVert y\rVert$? How is $\lVert y\rVert$ defined? That tells you something about the relation, and something about the set $\{\lVert x\rVert : x\in \pi^{-1}(y)\}$.

Comment: The last edit completely changed the question. It would have been much better if you would have opened a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

The claim follows from the triangle inequality and positive homogeneity of the norm: Take $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb R$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$. Then
$$
\|x-(\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda)t_2)y \|
= \| \lambda(x-t_1y)  +(1-\lambda) (x-t_2 y)\|
\le \lambda \|x-t_1y\|  + (1-\lambda) \|x-t_2 y\|
$$